# Unexpected token Illegal in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm

[image]

Trying command `cd` to change directive to `C:\xampp\htdocs\project`.

Facing issue with node.js cmd.

Comment: try process.chdir('/temp/foo');

Comment: NodeJS is not a shell like Bash : ), there is no keyword `cd` in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

first exit node, (ctrl+c) then cd to your directory.
You also probably need something like npm init/install/update what so ever.
You usually never need the node command unless for some obscure stuff :)

Good luck